# .htaccess help, not working when I changed servers

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am not very familiar with .htaccess and have already searched through the net but
couldn't find an explanation to what I have

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?mpage=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?mpage=$1
RewriteRule ^search-result/([^/\.]+)$ index.php?mpage=search-result&subpage=$1  [L]
RewriteRule ^search-result/([^/\.]+)/(.*)$ index.php?mpage=search-result&subpage=$1&act=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^online-result/([^/\.]+)$ index.php?mpage=online-result&subpage=$1  [L]
RewriteRule ^online-result/([^/\.]+)/(.*)$ index.php?mpage=online-result&subpage=$1&act=$2 [L]
```

This is an .htaccess to what I am building, this worked before on a GoDaddy server but
when changed server, it wont work any more.

Let say `http://www.mywebsite.com/home` worked before, because if you can see `mpage=$1` it replaces the get to the one on slash right? But when I change servers it will see a 404 error.

Any ideas what it could be?

Comment: The server might not recognize the `.htaccess` files. See [http://eddieringle.com/how-to-htaccess-not-working-maybe-apache-is-ignoring-it/](http://eddieringle.com/how-to-htaccess-not-working-maybe-apache-is-ignoring-it/) for more information.

Comment: Is Apache configured to read .htaccess? Is AllowOverride directive set on All? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#AllowOverride

Comment: why are there `<br />` tags in there ?

Comment: Sorry for the <br /> tags, new with stackoverflow, Godaddy said the Linux hosting has apache rewrite module enabled, but I tried to use the google redirect example but to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make sure you have the apache rewrite module enabled, and that AllowOverride is set to All in your vhost config

Comment: Godaddy said they have that enabled, but not sure why its not working, since on my PC localhost and old server it works,

Comment: Can you load http://mywebsite.com/index.php?mpage=home  You might also want to just switch hosts if godaddy is giving you problems, you can set up a cloudserver on rackspace cloud for 10 bucks a month, and you can configure it to your hearts content.